# How to copy file(s) in a dependency-aware manner, taking existence and time stamp into account

Tags: qt, qmake

I've faced a strange issue in qmake. 
I need `make` to **copy** a file according to its rules based on existence and time stamp. I have **subdirs** (`TEMPLATE=subdirs`) project type. I tried this:

```
__file = script.py
__target_file = $${DESTDIR}/$${__file}

my_target.target = $$__target_file
my_target.commands = cp -f $${__file} $${__target_file}
my_target.depends = $${__file}

all_target.target = all
all_target.depends = $${__target_file}

QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS *= my_target all_target
```

I use GNU Make to build this project for Linux and Mac OS.

The main problem here is that Makefile ends up with two rules for the `all` target. The first one is

```
all: FORCE
```

and the second one is my custom `all_target`.

In a situation like this, `make` call produces no result, and `make all` executes `all_target`.

If it was a `lib` or `app` project type, it would be easier, using qmake variable `POST_TARGETDEPS` to copy any extra dependecies.

P.S. I also need to be able to build this by Visual Studio 9.

Comment: I managed to solve this for GNU Make using `first` target. Unfortunately it does not work in Visual Studio at all :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to make this project as lib-type for Visual Studio 9 with empty source file `stub.c`. And use hacking approach to re-generate `stub.c` each time when `script.py` changes. It's very annoying.

Complete code for .pro-file:

```
TARGET = my_module

win32: TEMPLATE = lib
else: TEMPLATE = subdirs

SCRIPT_MODULE_FILE = script.py

__file = ...
__target_file = ...
__copy_cmd = ...

win32 {
   CONFIG *= staticlib
   DESTDIR = ...
   GENERATED_FILES = stub.c
   my_target.input = SCRIPT_MODULE_FILE
   my_target.output = stub.c
   my_target.commands = $${__copy_cmd} && copy /y nul stub.c > nul
   QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS *= my_target
}
else {
   my_target.target = $$__target_file
   my_target.commands = $$__copy_cmd
   my_target.depends = $${__file}
   first.depends = $(first) my_target
   QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS *= first my_target
}
```